deployment gitlab on cluster minikube on windows10
I tried to deploy gitlab on cluster minikube on windows10.
Checking the deployment on minikube all pods, deployments, services ... are green, but I can't access gitlab. After I entered root/initially provided password I always get the error 422 The change you requested was rejected
I deployed gitlab with the following command:
helm upgrade --install gitlab  gitlab/gitlab --version 7.8.2 --timeout 600s  -f .\gitlab-minikube.yaml  --namespace gitlab --set global.edition=ce
and the minimal settings:
Minimal settings
global:
ingress:
configureCertmanager: false
class: "nginx"
hosts:
domain: 192.168.49.2.nip.io
externalIP: 192.168.49.2
Disable Rails bootsnap cache (temporary)
rails:
bootsnap:
enabled: false
shell:
# Configure the clone link in the UI to include the high-numbered NodePort
# value from below (gitlab.gitlab-shell.service.nodePort)
port: 32022
Don't use certmanager, we'll self-sign
certmanager:
install: false
Use the ingress addon, not our Ingress (can't map 22/80/443)
nginx-ingress:
enabled: false
Save resources, only 3 CPU
prometheus:
install: false
gitlab-runner:
install: false
Reduce replica counts, reducing CPU & memory requirements
gitlab:
webservice:
minReplicas: 1
maxReplicas: 1
sidekiq:
minReplicas: 1
maxReplicas: 1
gitlab-shell:
minReplicas: 1
maxReplicas: 1
# Map gitlab-shell to a high-numbered NodePort to support cloning over SSH since
# Minikube takes port 22.
service:
type: NodePort
nodePort: 32022
registry:
hpa:
minReplicas: 1
maxReplicas: 1
than:
I forwarded all ports.
I can start gitlab and I can see the login page, but the login with root and the password I found in the secret gitlab-gitlab-initial-root-password fails.
